# DataTrigger Not Firing in DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I am trying to implement a DataTrigger on my DataGrid in XAML Code.
My Data grid consists of Datatable inside
But I couldnt get it whats wrong with my code because my trigger isnt firing.
I have searched many articles on internet but I dont know what wrong I am doing
Any help in the regard will be appreciated

Here is my XAML code

```
           <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ColumnWidth="*"  Grid.Row="0" AutoGeneratedColumns="DataGrid_HideOrMoveColumn"   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FaultDataView}"  x:Name="dataGrid_faultrec" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Black" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="10,20,10,10" FontSize="14" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns >
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Delete">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <!--<Button   x:Name="Delete_Fault" Content="Delete" Click="Delete_Fault_Click" Background="Red" />-->
                                        <Button   x:Name="Delete_Fault"  Click="Delete_Fault_Click" Background="White" >
                                            <Image Source="Resources\quit.png" Height="20" ></Image>
                                        </Button>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Edit ">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button   x:Name="Edit_Fault" Click="Edit_Fault_Click" Background="White" >
                                            <Image Source="Resources\pencil.png" Height="20"></Image>
                                        </Button>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>

                            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />

                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Flag}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Flag}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.RowStyle>

                    </DataGrid>
```

My Cs File Code

```
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        public bool Flag { get; set; }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }

        public void Add_Fault(List<faultview> _lastHeaderbody)
        {

            is_TP = false;
            is_continuous = false;
            is_doubtful = false;
            int i = 0;

            try
            {
                foreach (var row in _lastHeaderbody)
                {
                    // total_L_Points += row.Severity;
                    total_L_Points = GetTotalLinearPointFromDB(GetCurrentHeaderRollId());
                    faults.AddRange(_lastHeaderbody);

                }

                foreach (var row in _lastHeaderbody)
                {
                    DataRow dr = FaultDataTable.NewRow();
                    //dr["Meter"] = row["Location"];
                    foreach (var temp in fault_col_heading)
                    {
                        if (fault_bind_field[i] == "Location")
                        {
                            dr[temp] = row.Location;


                        }
                        if (fault_bind_field[i] == "StartMeter")
                        {
                            dr[temp] = row.StartMeter;

                        }

                        if (fault_bind_field[i] == "EndMeter")
                        {
                            dr[temp] = row.EndMeter;

                        }
                        else if (fault_bind_field[i] == "Severity")
                        {
                            dr[temp] = row.Severity;

                        }
                        else if (fault_bind_field[i] == "Description")
                        {
                            dr[temp] = row.Description;

                        }
                        else if (fault_bind_field[i] == "Type")
                        {
                            dr[temp] = row.Type;

                        }
                        else if (fault_bind_field[i] == "id")
                        {
                            dr[temp] = row.id;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //do nothing
                        }
                        i++;
                    }

                    if(_lastHeaderbody[0].Description== "Double Pick")
                    {
                       // is_TP = true;
                        Flag = true;
                        OnPropertyChanged("Flag");
                    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any binding errors in Output window when you debug this app?

Comment: Nopes No isses in binding but the trigger isnt firing

Comment: Try messing with the Binding UpdateSourceTrigger. For example `{Binding Fault, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`